# Можно ли изменять падежи слов в цитате?

Tags: падежи, цитата

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли изменять падежи слов в цитатах? В каких источниках об этом говорится?
Например, цитата такая: "исихастская традиция – это поистине средоточие или концентрированное выражение духовного опыта православного монашества".

Можно ли изменить так: ...специфика состоит в наследовании исихастской традиции, которая является "средоточием или концентрированным выражением духовного опыта православного монашества"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я почти полностью согласен с @МаркИз, при таком построении фразы цитата становится частью предложения, а члены предложения подчиняются грамматическим законами согласования и управления. По отношению к каноническим или догматическим источникам (как тексты Святого писания или труды Ленина и Сталина в советский период) такое не рекомендуется, их цитировать лучше дословно (даже "добуквенно"), но это явно не ваш случай.
Это по сути вопроса.

Теперь главное, то, что вы с Марком Изом обсуждаете. ***Источник нужен***, но ***кавычки я бы тут сохранил***. Дело не в согласии, но в приоритете (или копирайтах). Источник в квадратных скобках совсем не исключает упоминание автора высказывания, наоборот, скорее даже предполагает упоминания этого автора. Если, конечно, из предыдущего текста не ясно, кто этот автор. А уж если мысль вам понравилась, то упомянуть автора просто необходимо из простого уважения, да и стилистически фраза понятнее и доходчивее будет с таким атрибутом. Источник (конкретную работу, например)- да, не обязательно, точнее говоря - по вашему желанию, но имя здесь необходимо.

(++++++++)

После обсуждения в комментариях нашел вот это. Источник не авторитетный, но внешне вполне добротный.

> В научных работах распространен такой вид цитирования, как парафраз.
>   Так называется пересказ цитаты своими словами. В этом случае ссылка на
>   автора также обязательна, как и сохранение смысла при пересказе.
>   Парафраз уместен в следующих случаях:
>
> -предоставление обобщенной информации при ссылке на несколько источников;
>   -краткое изложение объемной теоретической концепции;
>   -объемные цитаты, неприменимые для прямого упоминания.
>
> Изменение цитаты допустимо только в особых случаях. Как правило это
>   нежелательно, но существуют случаи, когда ГОСТ Р 7.0.5_2008
>   «Библиографическая ссылка» и методические пособия разрешают внесение
>   авторских изменений в цитату:
>   ....
>   -При изменении падежа слов в цитате. Изменение допустимо только в том 
>   случае, если цитата подчиняется синтаксическому строю фразы, в
>   которую она включена.

https://moluch.ru/information/citation/

Там вообще много про цитирование рекомендую ознакомиться.

Comment: Тут дело не в копирайте. При таком построении фразы это пересказ чей-то мысли, а не прямое цитирование, поэтому ссылка нужна обязательно, а кавычки уже  факультативны.

Comment: Подождите, где "тут"? Я говорю о причинах, почему не стоит отказываться от кавычек при цитировании, даже в качестве члена предложения. И такое цитирование совсем не является "пересказом" (парафразом). Подробнее - в тексте моего ответа.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Решила не убирать кавычки, так как передача мысли всё-таки дословная, и всё-таки это другой человек сказал, а я только повторила.

Answer (score 2):

Грамматически ничто не мешает оформить цитату таким образом, но при этом возникает вопрос, а это чья цитата? Если вы согласны с этим мнением, то зачем кавычки? А если нет, то кто так считает?

Не являюсь специалистом в исихастской традиции, но уверен, что относятся к ней по разному и не все её так высок ставят. Поэтому если вы хотите сохранить нейтральность (а судя по отрывку текст написан в научном стиле), то рекомедую один из двух вариантов.

1. Специфика состоит в наследовании исихастской традиции, которая **по меткому варажению имярека** является "средоточием или концентрированным выражением духовного опыта православного монашества" (*если ваше мнение*)
2. специфика состоит в наследовании исихастской традиции, которая **по словам имярека** является "средоточием или концентрированным выражением духовного опыта православного монашества" (*если мнение кого-то другого*)

Comment: Можно уточнить по поводу этого: "Если вы согласны с этим мнением, то зачем кавычки? А если нет, то кто так считает?" Я согласна с этим мнением, но разве при согласии опускаются кавычки? Источник цитаты в любом случае будет указываться в квадратных скобках [5, c. 45]

Comment: @Юлия При косвенном цитировании кавычки необязательны. По сути вы не цитируете, а пересказываете ту или иную мысль. Такой подход лучше прямого цитирования,  так как увеличивает уникальность текста в автоматических системах проверки на плагиат.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Решила не убирать кавычки, так как передача мысли всё-таки дословная, и всё-таки это другой человек сказал, а я только повторила.